# 401k Matching: Why match 50 cents on a dollar up to 8% instead of dollar for dollar up to 4%?

Tags: 401k

What is the reason an employer would match 50 cents on every dollar up to 8% instead of matching 1 dollar on every dollar up to 4%? Is it the same or approximately the same thing?